# Rails 3 - Tidying Up Tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having an issue with article Tags where a user can write an article once they have signed-in and add tags to the bottom of the article... pretty standard stuff.

Am using the .titleised method which works fine, however I notice that if a user enters 3 tags without commas it then displays all these words as a single tag.

Is there a way I can automatically enter a comma after each word 'on submit' before they are entered into the db via the model even if the user doesn't ?

For example:  Red, Hot, Roof, instead of Red Hot Roof

models/article.rb

```
def assign_tags
if @tag_names
  self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\,/).map do |name|
    Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name.titleize)
```

models/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name
validates :name, :uniqueness => true

# order by creation
default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'

has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
has_many :articles, :through => :taggings
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
self.tags = @tag_names.split(/\,/).map do |name|
```

to

```
self.tags = @tag_names.split(/[\,\s]/).reject(&:blank?).map do |name|
```

thus splitting at commas AND whitespaces, and then removing any empty strings, and you should be fine.